# My co-worker and I are quitting together. We should give notice together too?

Tags: new-job, job-change, spain

My co-worker and I will quit our current jobs to join another company soon (First work day is next year). We are experienced members of our project and there are many unexperienced new people working on the same project.

We have to give notice to our current manager. I have two questions:

- Should we wait until it's closer to our start date to give notice?
- Should we give our notice together or separately?

I am searching pros and cons and other valuables experiences to make the best decision possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your locale? This information will be important in determining how much notice is customary for a resignation.

Comment: Spain. My country's law say 15 calendar days to notice

Comment: Why would you give notice together? Are you going to write one resignation and both sign it?

Comment: Because We work together (same project) and we leave to same company, same date. We think it's more serious call our manager one time instead two for same notice (Anyway, I accept suggerences and tips, this is my first time quitting)

Comment: yep, it's true. Only that the other way looks like hidding that We knew each other's situation. Anyway I now see clearful that must speak one to one with our manager without other workers. These meeting can touch personal or professional topics and We don't need stay in the other.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere on the other side, if they do it separately, but at the same day for the 15 day notice period, that would look silly for the second one isn't it ? In all honesty, whether this will burn some bridge will more depends on the manager than anything I guess. Honesty like "we'll join a common friend together" can work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should we wait until it's closer to our start date to give notice?

As has been said in the comments there isn't much reason to give notice beyond what is required in your contact/legal obligations.

> Should we give our notice together or separately?

It's a little bit..*weird*  to do it together in my opinion. Given the fact that you both work on the same project, are leaving on the same day and are going to the same company giving notice together may well give a strong impression of this being a co-ordinated move. Something many employers may take negatively - and while you are leaving this employer their's little benefit to burning bridges on the way out so I would do it separately.

Comment: It really is a "coordinated" movement. A common friend (former co-worker) was looking for developers in his new job and contact with us with an excellent job offer. I feel really weird too but It is too strange that we give the notice with little time difference or with the same end date. I am worried about how to make a good communication about this.

Comment: @Genaut I'd still be inclined to avoid that optic. Additionally resignation chats really are supposed to be between two parties - employer and employee, having someone else there resigning would make it feel awkward. There's not much you can do about the fact that you're both going to be resigning on the same day but basically slapping them in the face with that feels hugely unprofessional to me.

Comment: You are right. Maybe our manager can tell us some personal and it's better than nobody more stay in the same place on these moment. I want make this more professional as possible and you are helping me a lot. Thanks

Comment: At least in my country (Canada) there's usually a clause in the "typical" employment contract that says you can't solicit other employees away from the company you're leaving for a period of time after you yourself quit.  I'm not sure how an employer would read this situation if you both quit together, but I wouldn't want to find out the hard way.  If you each quit separately, you can each independently cite the common friend as your reason for leaving (if they ask) and that way avoid suspicion that one of you "solicited" the other into doing this "together."

Comment: @Steve-O similar clauses are pretty common here in the UK as well

Comment: No poaching clauses are really common in the USA too. I had to sign one when I left my last company that stays effective for 1 year. I would not introduce this topic in case your company wants to pursue and complicate your life.

Answer (score 2):

Spread out your notices by at least a week, if you both have the freedom to do so. From what you've informed in the question, it seems like it'd affect your current company negatively if both of you leave. Spreading it out by a week or two will give them the time to prepare/reflect on the same.

Answer (score 1):

Given how you re senior members of the project and most likely relied upon, I would personally go beyond the mandated time-frame of leave notice and inform the employer in advance. Note that seniority of the position also makes it harder to fill so while for some positions a week may be enough, for others months are required. On your specific situation, I would say a month sounds about right if you want to be courteous and leave the company on a good note that is.

Doing this allows them time to find your replacement and also have you train them/onboard them on specifics if need be during your time left there assuming you re asked to do so. Your employer will surely be grateful for not having to scramble at the last moment due to your courtesy.

I will also agree on the part of Motosubatsu's answer that resignation notices should be given out separately to avoid theories of mutiny arising, and avoiding potential conflicts with contract clauses about poaching employers/soliciting other employers away from the firm.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85716/discussion-on-answer-by-leon-my-co-worker-and-i-are-quitting-together-we-should).